# How can I get the information from user instead of using specific values?

Tags: c++, function, class, getter-setter

Edited.Hello again I am new in here and also in C++.I want to write a code that I can use functions and classes in a basic way.I asked from the user ID,name,salary in the main function.Btw no error occurred before compiling and program asked the user ID however skipped the name which I defined with string.Then continue with taking salary.Why it is not taking a string value?At the end of the code I add the output

```
enter code here
 #include<string>
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 class Employee
  {
   private:
   int eid;
   string name;
   public:
   Employee(int e,string n)
   {
    eid=e;
    name=n;
    setEmployeeID(e);
    setName(n);
    }
    void setEmployeeID(int e)
    {
     eid=e;
    }
     int getEmployeeID()
    {
     return eid;
    }
     void setName(string n)
    {
     name=n;
     }
     string getName()
     {
     return name;
     }
     };
 class FulltimeEmployee:public Employee
     {
     private:
        int salary;
     public:
        FulltimeEmployee(int e,string n,int sal):Employee(e,n)
      {
      salary=sal;
      setSalary(sal);
       }
      void setSalary(int sal)
       {
      salary=sal;
       }
     int getSalary()
       {
     return salary;
        }
        };
class ParttimeEmployee:public Employee
     {
     private:
     int wage;
     public:
     ParttimeEmployee(int e,string n,int w):Employee(e,n)
     {
     wage=w;
     setWage(w);
     }
     void setWage(int w)
     {
      wage=w;
      }
      int getWage()
     {
     return wage;
      }
      };
int main()
{
int workerId;
string workerName;
int workerPayment;
cout<<"Please enter your ID please: ";
cin>>workerId;
cout<<"Please enter your name please: ";
cout<<"Please enter your salary: ";
getline(cin,workerName);
cin>>workerPayment;
ParttimeEmployee personel1(workerId,workerName,workerPayment);
FulltimeEmployee personel2(workerId,workerName,workerPayment);;
cout<<"Daily wage of "<<personel1.getName()<<" is "<<" "   <<personel1.getWage()<<endl;
cout<<"Worker ID is:"<<personel1.getEmployeeID()<<endl;
cout<<"Salary of "<<personel2.getName()<<"is "<<" "<<personel2.getSalary()<<endl;
  cout<<"Worker ID is:"<<personel2.getEmployeeID()<<endl;
  return 0;

  }


enter code here
Here is my output:
Please enter your ID please: 12123
Please enter your name please: Please enter your salary: 1000
Daily wage of  is  1000
Worker ID is:12123
Salary of is  1000
```

Comment: I recommend showing what you tried. It's hard to help you solve what you got wrong when you leave the stuff that's wrong out of the question.

Comment: Consider 'Tell, Don't Ask', "which reminds us to instead put the behavior inside the object itself (using the same fields).",  Thus,  "cout << "Daily wage of " << personel1.getName() << " is " << personel1.getWage() << endl;" becomes personel1.showDailyWage(); ... and you add the method "PartTimeEmployee::showDailyWage()"   For user input, you add "PartTimeEmployee::updateWage()" and it will prompt and validate the new wage, then show the updated info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild guess, but you could use `cin`:

```
class Employee
{
//...
public:
     void get_info_from_user()
     {
         std::cout << "Enter employee ID: ";
         std::cin >> eid;
         std::cout << "Enter employee name: ";
         std::getline(std::cin, name);
     };
};
```

You can add something similar to the other classes as well.

**Edit 1: overloading operator>>**
For more genericity, you could overload `operator>>`:

```
class Employee
{
//...
  public:
      friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Employee& e);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Employee& e)
{
    input >> e.eid;
    std::getline(input, e.name);
    return input;
}
```

The above code allows you to do things like this:

```
std::vector<Employee> database;
Employee e;
while (data_file >> e)
{
    database.push_back(e);
}
```

Comment: Let's be honest. This isn't all that wild of a guess. Could use more leprechauns.